# Django, merging two objects

Tags: python, django, object

I have two objects

```
article_category = ArticleCategory.objects.all()
project_category = ProjectCategory.objects.all()
```

I want to merge these two in one so that I can access them with one object.

something like this.

```
category = add(article_category,project_category)
```

what is the way to do this in Django ?